# OR condition in linux makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

```
ifeq (ABC,$(strip $(TYPE)))
include src1.mk
else ifeq (EFG,$(strip $(TYPE)))
include src1.mk
else
include src2.mk
```

How to combine the above two conditions.

I tried this

```
ifeq ($(TYPE),$(filter $(TYPE),ABC EFG))
include src1.mk
else
include src2.mk
```

but it is not behaving properly, even if TYPE is not ABC or EFG it is entering in if case.

Comment: Please show a complete example that demonstrates it not behaving properly. That looks like it should work.

Comment: Mean to say even if TYPE is not defined either to ABC or EFG it is entering in if condition.

Comment: Yes, you already said that in the question. But I don't believe you :-P Please show a **complete** example (including setting TYPE to some other value) and evidence it enters the first branch of the `if` (e.g. replace the `include` with `$(info condition is true)`). What you have shown is not complete and not valid (for a start it's missing the `endif`) so it's not possible to tell why your **real** makefile isn't working.

Comment: Did losing `strip` hurt that comparison? Does `TYPE` contain a `%`? Is the problem when` $(TYPE)` is empty? (Because an empty argument to filter is going to return empty which will match itself.)

Comment: Yes , in my case TYPE can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifneq ($(filter $(TYPE),ABC EFG),)
```

I have the following:

```
ifneq ($(filter $(TYPE),ABC EFG),)
 $(info TYPE is in ABC EFG)
endif

ifeq ($(TYPE),$(filter $(TYPE),ABC EFG))
 $(info Ruchis test passed)
endif

all:
        @# do nothing
```

Then I run

```
~/tmp> make TYPE=ABC
TYPE is in ABC EFG
Ruchis test passed

~/tmp> make TYPE=EFG
TYPE is in ABC EFG
Ruchis test passed

~/tmp> make TYPE=HIJ

~/tmp> make TYPE=
Ruchis test passed
```

Your test gives a false positive if `$(TYPE)` is empty.